# How to know when a program finished when they run in background?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, arcgis, arcpy

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 to create an interface. I'm using Python 2.7 to call and run Gams in background using

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call([r"C:\GAMS\win64\24.4\gamside.exe",r"C:\Users\sofia\Downloads\file_name.gms"])
```

After gams runs, it exports excel files and I need a way to know this program finished run and open this excel results files. How can I know when gams finished run? Is it possible by sending a flag or another method?

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

> **subprocess.check_call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)**
>
> Run command with arguments. Wait for command to
>   complete. If the return code was zero then return, otherwise raise
>   CalledProcessError. The CalledProcessError object will have the return
>   code in the returncode attribute.

Simply wrap you call with try/except and check the exit code and you'll know if it finished successfully or not.